# expressja make http request using xhr or fetch

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple `expressjs` script like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var requestAuth = function (req, res, next) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  console.log("a", xhr)
  next()
}
app.use(requestAuth)

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello again</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here I want to make simple ajax call and check for authentication in url.

Whhen I execuste the above script it gives me error like `XMLHttpRequest` is not defined. What is the issue here ?

Same type of error I got when I tried using `promise`

How can I make http request using xhr or fetch ?

Isnt it nodejs should accept all the functions that normal javascript accept ?

Can anyone make me more clear ? I am very new to expressjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not requrie module xmlhttprequest require it like that. 
first run command

```
npm install xmlhttprequest --save
```

then require ("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

```
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

It will work perfectly fine even if you remove this part of code from your app. i.e

```
var requestAuth = function (req, res, next) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  console.log("a", xhr)
  next()
}
app.use(requestAuth)
```